# 特定のワークスペースでEmEditorを起動したい

Tags: emeditor

EmEditorを起動しない状態で、\Emurasoft\EmEditor\Workspaceにある特定のワークスペース「＊.eeWorkspace」をEmEditor workspace programで開くことができません。

何らかのショートカットファイルを作成するなどして、EmEditorを起動すると自動的に特定のワークスペースが開くという方法はありますでしょうか。

スタートウィンドウには「最近のワークスペース」の項目があり、その中に特定のワークスペースが表示されるのですが、この特定のワークスペースを毎回選択する手間を省きたいのです。最近利用したファイルのように、ワークスペースについても、右クリックすれば、「この(お気に入りの)一覧に常に表示」が出る機能があれば少し便利なのですが。

ご教授のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コマンドラインで、

`/wsf "WorkspaceFile"`

と指定すれば、指定したワークスペース ファイルを開くようになります。これをショート カットに指定すればご希望のことが可能です。

コマンド ラインについて詳しくは、[コマンド ラインを指定するには](http://www.emeditor.org/ja/howto_file_file_commandline.html)  をご参照ください。

Comment: 早速にありがとうございます。希望どおりのことができました。